# Не получается в асинхронном режиме получать данные от сервера

Tags: python, websocket, asyncio

Проблема с асинхронным получением данных от сервера.
Если синхронно через функцию обращаться к серверу, то программа замирает, пока не придет какой-то ответ.
При оборачивании функции в Task работает асинхронно, но не выдает ответы от сервера. Выдает только первый ответ (в примере def send_msg).
Что я делаю не так?

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import time

def channel_msg(ch_send):

msg = \
    {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "method": "public/subscribe",
     "id": 42,
     "params": {
         "channels": ch_send

     }
     }

    return msg

async def connect():
    global websocket
    websocket = await websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2')

async def send_msg(message):
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(message))
    return

async def recv():

    return await websocket.recv()

async def main():
    await connect()
    ch_send = ["book.BTC-PERPETUAL.none.10.100ms"]
    msg = channel_msg(ch_send)
    await send_msg(msg)
    task = asyncio.create_task(recv())
    await task

    while True:

        print(await task) #здесь через task

        # print(await recv()) #здесь через синхронную функцию

        print(f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Боже, выкини 70% строчек кода...

Comment: Ваше предложение?

Answer (score 1):

`print(await recv())` это асинхронная функция. правильно через неё, таск не нужен в этом коде.

Comment: Через await recv() программа замирает до получения сообщения. Оно может прийти и через 100 мс и через несколько секунд. Мне же нужно чтобы в момент ожидания ответа программа выполняла другие задачи

Comment: А что она должна делать пока ждёт?

Comment: Мне нужно в определенный момент времени отправлять запрос серверу.

Comment: не вижу в вашем коде попыток этого.

`loop.call_at()` для запуска чегото в определенное время пока ждет ават

Answer (score 0):

**Синхронный** вызов функций - это когда каждая последующая функция вызывается строго после предыдущей.

**Асинхронный** вызов функций - когда следующие функции вызываются не дожидаясь завершения предыдущих.

То, что Вы перед описанием каждой функции в Вашей программе поставили слово *async*, отнюдь не сделало эту программу асинхронной. Потому, что перед вызовом каждой следующей функции Вы используете *await*. И это не зависит от того, как Вы запускаете функцию - явно, или через задачу. Это определяется логикой Вашего кода, а не чем-то другим.

> Выдает только первый ответ

А почему должно быть  ответов больше одного?  Внутри цикла стоит только чтение.  А сервер (любой) всегда только отвечает на запрос. А запрос - это операция записи (отправки сообщения) на сервер.

Comment: Я знаю, что по сути код не асинхронный. Мне нужно асинхронными сделать две задачи: установление соединения с сервером и поддержание его открытым (это работает) и получение ответа.
Ответов должно быть больше одного, потому что я подписываюсь на канал вебсокета, и он постоянно шлет данные которые обновились.
Я только изучаю вебсокеты и асинхронное программирование и мне пока сложно правильно соединить это все вместе.

Comment: Никакой асинхронности здесь использовать нет нужды. У вас сугубо **последовательный** алгоритм: 1) Устанавливаем соединение 2) Цикл приёма сообщений. Цикл тоже абсолютно последовательный: 1) Приняли сообщение 2) Обработали сообщение.

Comment: То, что Вы пишите - это абсолютно **стандарный** клиент для какого-то сервера. Технолгии написания клиентов настолько стандартизованы, что я не буду тут расписывать. Ну, если совсем с нуля, то прочтите хотя бы это: https://habr.com/ru/articles/580710/